# having done the paperwork

Tags: conditionals

I wanna tell someone that I would like to do something before finishing the paperwork, which one is correct:

1- I would like to start, even before having the paperwork done.
2- I would like to start, even before having done the paperwork.

or perhaps there is a better way to explain that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to start this before finishing the paperwork** would probably be best.

Comment: OP actually mentions this adverbial.